# javascript <a> link doesn't work by clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink

In order to implement a JavaScript app, we have to implement something like the code below. But once the Google link has been clicked, the user isn't redirected to the www.google.fr.

Do you have the same problem? Any solution?

```js
        $('#myCheckLink').click(function(){
        var x = document.getElementById("myCheckLink").checked;
        if(x === true){
          $('#label').append('<a href="http://www.google.fr" id="link">Google</a>');
        }else{
          $('#link').remove();
        }
            
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label id="label">
    <input type="checkbox" id="myCheckLink">
    </label>
```

Comment: It's because of the tag <label> which tries to check the box on click

Comment: Why don't you add `target="_blank"`this!

Comment: You cannot put `<a>` elements inside `<label>` elements - this is the cause of your problem.

Comment: Did you check the console? `Mixed Content: The page at '' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://www.google.fr/'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

Comment: Change to `https` gives: `1 Refused to display 'https://www.google.fr/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of appending to your label, maybe you should make div around it and append your `a` to that `div`, styling will be remain same, but it should work now. As an alternative you can try using `target=_blank` with your original code.

```js
$('#myCheckLink').click(function(){
        var x = document.getElementById("myCheckLink").checked;
        if(x === true){
          $('.test').append('<a href="https://www.google.fr" id="link">Google</a>');
        }else{
          $('#link').remove();
        }
            
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='test'>
  <label id="label">
    <input type="checkbox" id="myCheckLink">
  </label>  
</div>
```

PS: It won't work on stackoverflow.

Comment: @Cr1xus Stackoverflow doesn't allow links to be opened in new window. No need to downvote.

Comment: Where does the OP state they want to open a new window/tab?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan He doesn't but it could still be viable solution for his issue. I see you have found real issue with his code. I will delete my answer.

Comment: There must be a better solution. I deleted my Answer because of this.

Comment: @Zvezdas1989 I see, I tried with <p> instead of <label> and it still doesn't doesn't work, so it's so. PS I didn't downvote your answer

Comment: @Cr1xus I have changed my answer can you give it a try on your website or locally if that is where you are developing it.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have edited my answer I hope it's better.

Comment: Currently, all the solutions didn't work. Maybe I suspect a delegate function in my code, which interferes with the anchor "link". Is it possible ?

Nobody has a solution to prevent the delegate function from acting on anchor behaviour ?

Thanks.

Comment: @floriandaniel Yes it's possible but we would need all your code to see what is happening.